# I'm trying to write a POST request to my API so that it can act on two separate objects(an insert and an update)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to write this controller that accepts a POST request.

I need this controller to add a new book, and also add that new books bookId to another object called a StoreList.

So I am trying to pass in the new bookList, and the storeList that needs the bookId added to it.

```
    // POST: api/BookList
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<BookList>> PostBookList(BookList bookList, StoreList storeList)
    {
        _context.BookList.Add(bookList);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _context.Entry(storeList).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!StoreListExists(storeId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetBookList", new { id = bookList.BookId }, bookList);
    }
```

Here is my API endpoint:

> https://localhost:44362/api/BookList/

And these are the two objects I'm passing in the BODY of the request (the new bookList and the existing storeList):

```
{
    "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7",
    "bookTitle": "Is this a test 2?"
},
{
    "storeId": "0001f801-6909-4b6e-8652-e1b49745280f",
    "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7"
}
```

But whenever I try to 'hit' that endpoint, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Action
>   'DocumentStorageAPI.Controllers.Book.BookListController.PostBookList
>   (DocumentStorageAPI)'    has more than one parameter that was
>   specified or inferred as bound from request body.    Only one
>   parameter per action may be bound from body.    Inspect the following
>   parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to specify bound from query, 
>   'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from route, and
>   'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body: BookList
>   bookList StoreList storeList

How can I get my controller to allow me to add a new bookList and update the needed storeList?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the request should be just one object and the `PostBookList` method must have only one parameter (with the `[FromBody]` attribute). If you need both classes to use within the method create a new class like this:

```
public class PostBookListRequest
{
    public BookList BookList { get; set; }
    public StoreList StoreList { get; set; }
}
```

change the `PostBookList` method to

```
public async Task<ActionResult<BookList>> PostBookList([FromBody]PostBookListRequest request)
{
    // Your logic here
}
```

And in the BODY of the request do

```
{
    "bookList": {
        "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7",
        "bookTitle": "Is this a test 2?"
    },
    "storeList": {
        "storeId": "0001f801-6909-4b6e-8652-e1b49745280f",
        "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, but how would I create the new book and also update the store object?  Would the controller know how to handle an object like the one you posted above?  thanks!

Comment: How have you defined your models? What properties does a BookList have? And StoreList? Are collections or just entities? I think the List part in the name is confusing.

Comment: The names are confusing since it's not really a book store but a memory store. :) They are both separate models and the only thing they share is the bookId.  A storeId has a bookId field which can either be null or refer to one of the books in the bookList. A store can only have one book and a question can only be part of one store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use body like this:

```
{
  "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7",
  "title": "Is this a test 2?",
  "storeId" "0001f801-6909-4b6e-8652-e1b49745280f"
}
```

In Controller you need additional class BookListBinding with this 3 fields, which you will use for create you 2 objects, for example.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostBookList(BookListBinding binding)
{
    var bookList = new BookList
    {
        Id = binding.BookId,
        Title = binding.Title 
    });

    var storeList = new StoreList
    {
       Id = binding.StoreId,
       BookId = binding.BookId
    }

    // you work with _context

    return CreatedAtAction("GetBookList", new { id = binding.BookId }, bookList);
}
```

Why you need change StoreList? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new model like so-

```cs
public class AddBookToStoreModel
    {
        public Book BookToAdd { get; set; }
        public StoreList BookStoreList { get; set; }
    }
```

You have to add the same to the controller definition, like this-

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<BookStore>> PostBookList(AddBookToStoreModel model)
```

Also you need to create the individual Models for Book and StoreList like below-

```cs
public class Book
    {
        public Guid BookId { get; set; }
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    }

public class StoreList
    {
        public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
        public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    }
```

The Json that you post to the controller will look like below-

```
{
"BookToAdd": {
    "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7",
    "bookTitle": "Is this a test 2?"
},
"BookStoreList": {
    "storeId": "0001f801-6909-4b6e-8652-e1b49745280f",
    "bookId": "bc381612-c63b-4438-b35b-161a3a568fc7"
}
}
```

I hope this works for you.